# How to change the master volume in PulseAudio programmatically?

Tags: python, pulse-audio

You can change the master volume within the *terminal* itself by using the command shown underneath.

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
```

However, when I tried to execute the following code in *Python*, the following error is shown.

```
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

amixer: Mixer attach pulse error: Connection refused
```

And here is the code producing the error above.

```
os.system("amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+")
```

How does one resolve that error?

Comment: The "unable to connect" error can mean: pulseaudio is not running or permissions issues exist. "pactl" may be more appropriate for controlling pulseaudio. Try determine what output you're trying to control by running: "pactl list sinks". Review the output of that command to determine the sink number. Then run something like "pactl set-sink-volue 3 +5%"  (where "3" is the sink # on my machine for "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"). One point to note: sink numbers can change across reboots, so it is worthwhile to research how to accomplish the same thing with sink names instead of sink numbers.

Comment: I have tried pactl also but getting same errors.@joat

Comment: Pulseaudio is running?  Are you (or your script) running pactl/amixer as the logged in user (not root)?  That's about all that I can think of.

Comment: Of course it's working in terminal but my main issue is that it's not working with Python code.@joat

Comment: It's must be a permissions issue.  'import os;os.system("pactl set-sink-mute 3 1")' works if I run it in a terminal or in a script.  When you run amixer, do you have to select the sound card before doing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution to my own problem which is shown below

```
    import subprocess
    proc = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/amixer sset Master 5%', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.wait()
```